# how to get json data array with for loop

Tags: laravel, loops, for-loop

I have a question about for loop. 
I am saving json data just in one column. 
For example:

```
1 / John / ["jsondata1","jsondata2","jsondata3"]
2 / Elizabeth / ["jsondata3","jsondata4"]
```

I need to show this values in a table. 3rd column max data size is allways 4. there is no jsondata5

I was created this loop in my blade view.

```
<table>
@foreach($values  as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
        @for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
        <td>{{$value->jsondata[$i]}}</td>
        @endfor
    </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

In this case i am getting some errors. 
Error is `"Undefined offset: 2"`

When i tried `for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)`

it just show the last 2 data.
But if i tried `$i < 4` 
there is an error.

What is the right way to do this for loop?
I tried so much ways.

Comment: json_decode($payload) ?

Comment: i used json_decode in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to use casting. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model

Add this to the model and you'll be able to work with JSON data as with a simple array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'column_name' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: thats a great hidden feature.

Comment: Its already added. I tried this today but i couldn't make it.

Comment: You solved my all issues @Alexey Mezenin I am believing you can give me the solution. I got still same problem.

Comment: @AliÖzen please show results of `{{ dd($values) }}`